# coding to an interface, in a list - syntax

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, interface

I have extracted some of my concrete classes into interfaces

I used to have a class called `City`, and it implements interface `ICity`

now i tried to do the following

```
public List<ICity> Cities { get; private set; }

var efCities = (from c in myentity.Cities  
                  orderby c.CityName
                  select c);

Cities = (efCities.Select(o => new City() { Id = o.Id, Country = o.Country, 
          Province = o.Province, CityName = o.CityName }).ToList());
```

I get tuned the following:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<City>`'
>   to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<ICity>`'

as i understood it, since `City` implements `ICity`, i should be fine, no?
Isn't what I am doing in the same vein as going:

```
ICity c = new City();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `List<City>` is not that same as `List<ICity>.` Instead of assigning the select.toList(); to cities try something like:

`Cities.AddRange((efCities.Select(o => new City() { Id = o.Id, Country = o.Country, Province = o.Province, CityName = o.CityName }))`

Comment: Just an FYI: make sure you call Cities.Clear() if you have to run this code more than once or it will duplicate your List contents instead of replacing them.

Answer (score 10):

No one has really said the *reason* why this doesn't work.  Suppose Apple and Orange both implement IFruit:

```
List<Orange> oranges = new List<Orange>();
List<IFruit> fruits = oranges; // You are trying to do this, which is illegal.
                               // Suppose it were legal. Then you could do this:
fruits.Add(new Apple());
```

Because you can add an apple to a list of fruits, but that list is really a list of oranges! You just put an apple into a list of oranges, and apples are not oranges.

The C# compiler knows that this could happen, so it disallows it.  Unfortunately, it does not disallow that for *arrays*:

```
Orange[] oranges = new Orange[1];
IFruit[] fruits = oranges; // dangerous, but legal!
fruits[0] = new Apple(); // legal at compile time, crashes at runtime.
```

This is a form of *unsafe covariance*. We decided to not allow the same dangerous pattern for interfaces; interfaces can only be covariant if the compiler can prove that such an error is impossible.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, generic type parameters do not follow the same typecasting rules as stand-alone types. They are restricted by what the generic type says it allows; this is called *covariance* and *contravariance* and, in C#, only arrays, interfaces and delegates can be covariant or contravariant. Concrete types like `List` cannot be (at least, as of C# 4.0).

(The reason generics don't work the way you think *in general* is because its impossible to know what the generic type does with its type parameters; covariance is intuitive because that's how simple assignments works, but in many cases what we really want is contravariance; since the compiler cannot make the decision for us, it defaults to neither unless you say otherwise.)

For more information on co/contravariance in C# 4 I'd recommend you check out Eric Lippert's series of posts about it, in particular:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/30/what-s-the-difference-between-covariance-and-assignment-compatibility.aspx

and the MSDN article about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Fortunately, in this case there is a simple answer, the explicit `IEnumerable.Cast` method:

```
Cities = (efCities.Select(o => new City() { Id = o.Id, Country = o.Country, 
          Province = o.Province, CityName = o.CityName }).Cast<ICity>.ToList());
```

Another option is to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`. `IEnumerable<T>` *is* covariant in `T` so your assignment would work:

```
interface IA
{
  int Foo();
}

class A : IA
{
  public int Foo()
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

public DoStuff()
{
  List<A> la = new List<A> { new A(), new A(), new A(), new A() };

  // This is an error -- List<A> is not covariant with List<IA>
  // List<IA> lia = la;  

  // This is fine; List<A> implements IEnumerable<A>
  IEnumerable<A> iea = la; 

  // Also fine: IEnumerable<A> is covariant with IEnumerable<IA>
  IEnumerable<IA> ieia = la;     
}
```

Comment: pfft. why give someone a clear explanation and multiple options to pick from when you can just throw out something and get 15 rep? :\

Comment: TL;DR  jk - I gave you +1. Some people just want the answer, other people want the explination. *shrugs*

Comment: I'll rescind my answer since it is untested.

Comment: don't do that. it's right, its just not "exactly" what was asked for; calling it incorrect was way too harsh. And there's always something to say for being succinct :) Maybe just edit my comment into your answer for completeness? Having the right answer is more important that who gave it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not same as

```
ICity c = new City();
```

`List<ICity>` and `List<City>` are tehmselves types, and `List<City>` is not derived from `List<ICity>`.

Adding a cast to the selection would solve the problem:

```
Cities = (efCities.Select(o => (ICity)(new City() { Id = o.Id, Country = o.Country, 
          Province = o.Province, CityName = o.CityName })).ToList());
```